# What's the right course of action here?

Tags: discussion, edits

While checking out the review interface today, I happened upon [this original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453090/table-row-as-a-form/5993034#5993034) written by this user that eventually led me to [this second question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989787/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation-edit-html-table-row).

I flagged the original question as too localized (although I'm not really sure that was the right flag for the situation), but I'm here because of the second question.

I really feel like this is a grey-area situation. This user has (ostensibly) edited the solution to his/her question into the question itself. Editing that would fall outside the bounds of the valid edits -- at least as I understand them. I don't have edit privileges, but even if I did: what's the right way to "fix" the problem in the second question? Should I:

1. Suggest an edit to the accepted answer, and suggest an edit to the question as well?
2. Leave a comment for the original author and hope that he/she acts on my comment?
3. Flag the question? If yes, what flag is applicable in this situation?

I left a comment, changed my mind, deleted that comment, and started to flag for ♦ moderator attention. However, I know the moderators are swamped...so I'm here to (likely) spend moderator time anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I closed both questions as too localized.

If the OP had followed the Question/Answer format instead of treating the site like a forum, I might have been able to shuffle things around a bit and make it work.  But it's a dog's breakfast as it is.

Comment: Understood. So, flagging questions like these is ultimately the right response?

Comment: Yes.  When you leave a flag on questions like this, it's OK to just leave a description of the problem, or simply say "I don't really know what's going on here," and a mod will figure it out.

Comment: +1 for "dog's breakfast".